# Calculate Time Difference Between End of Conversation A and start of conversation B for each customer

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

Here is my query so far

```
SELECT  
user_id,
    conversation_id,
      LAG(end_time)
      OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY start_time) AS last_convo
      (unix_timestamp(start_time) - lag(unix_timestamp(end_time)))/60
    OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY start_time) AS time_between_end_newstart
FROM    mt_data
ORDER BY user_id
```

I have user_id, conversation_id, start_time, end_time for each conversation. What I am looking for is the time between when conversation A ends and conversation B starts for each customer(if they have multiple). Getting the results per customer and where the calculation starts from the very first convo for each customer is what I am struggling with. Thanks for some pro tips in advance

```
|user_id|conversation_id|start_time         |end_time           |
|-------|---------------|-------------------|-------------------|
|A      |123            |2021-09-21 00:22:50|2021-09-21 00:28:07|
|B      |122            |2021-09-21 07:56:00|2021-09-21 09:54:36|
|B      |111            |2021-09-21 09:55:33|2021-09-21 10:19:08|


Desired outcome

|user_id|conversation_id|start_time         |end_time           |time_between_end_newstart|
|-------|---------------|-------------------|-------------------|-------------------------
|A      |123            |2021-09-21 00:22:50|2021-09-21 00:28:07|0
|B      |122            |2021-09-21 07:56:00|2021-09-21 09:54:36|0
|B      |111            |2021-09-21 09:55:33|2021-09-21 10:19:08|0:00:57
```

Comment: Could you edit the question to contain the real SQL?  The current statement doesn't appear to be valid.  Also, it can help to provide the `CREATE TABLE` statements for each table.

Comment: Btw, I noticed you've never accepted an answer to any of your questions.  Are you not familiar with how to `accept an answer`, or were they all wrong (or not helpful)?  See the following, if you're interested: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: what do you mean by real sql? and why do we need to create a table for this?

thanks link to accept an answer was super helpful, i am super new to  stack overflowing and pro tips help

Comment: A test case includes the table `mt_data` with just enough data to produce the actual or expected result.  By `real SQL`, I mean you didn't report any errors.  Your SQL doesn't appear valid and will likely produce errors.  It wasn't simply SQL that produces wrong results.  I created a test case. I can post that in the answer as an example.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a starting point, with the errors removed and `LAG` properly used:

```
SELECT user_id
     , conversation_id
     , start_time
     , end_time
     , COALESCE(
       (      unix_timestamp(start_time)
        - lag(unix_timestamp(end_time  )) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY start_time)
       ), 0)  AS time_between_end_newstart
  FROM mt_data
 ORDER BY user_id, start_time
;

This result isn't with hadoop, but with a database which has similar support.

+---------+-----------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------------+
| user_id | conversation_id | start_time          | end_time            | time_between_end_newstart |
+---------+-----------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------------+
| A       |             123 | 2021-09-21 00:22:50 | 2021-09-21 00:28:07 |                         0 |
| B       |             122 | 2021-09-21 07:56:00 | 2021-09-21 09:54:36 |                         0 |
| B       |             111 | 2021-09-21 09:55:33 | 2021-09-21 10:19:08 |                        57 |
+---------+-----------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------------+
```

I don't have access to `hadoop` for testing, but if the above works for you, the only step left is proper formatting of the time difference.

Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT user_id
     , conversation_id
     , start_time
     , end_time
     , COALESCE(
            from_unixtime(
                (      unix_timestamp(start_time)
                 - lag(unix_timestamp(end_time  )) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY start_time)
                )
              , 'HH:mm:ss'
            )
         , 0
       )  AS time_between_end_newstart
  FROM mt_data
 ORDER BY user_id, start_time
;
```

Sorry, I can't test this one either.

**The following is the setup I used as a test case (using a different database), as an example:**

```
CREATE TABLE mt_data (
    user_id          varchar(10)
  , conversation_id  int
  , start_time       datetime
  , end_time         datetime
);

INSERT INTO mt_data VALUES
  ('A'      ,123            ,'2021-09-21 00:22:50','2021-09-21 00:28:07')
, ('B'      ,122            ,'2021-09-21 07:56:00','2021-09-21 09:54:36')
, ('B'      ,111            ,'2021-09-21 09:55:33','2021-09-21 10:19:08')
;
```

Comment: what is the advantage of adding COALESCE() to the script

Comment: @YevaMuradyan Your expected result contains 0's for the cases where `LAG` would produce a null.  To convert the null to 0, we use `COALESCE`.  This is standard SQL.

Comment: @YevaMuradyan Note that `from_unixtime` will also likely produce `null` for those cases.  To obtain 0 in the result requires that extra step (`COALESCE`) or the equivalent.

Comment: @YevaMuradyan Did the suggested query produce reasonable / acceptable results?

Comment: it did not so I am trying to understand why, time_between_end_newstart came back as 0 and user_id and rest of the columns were NULLS

Comment: @YevaMuradyan `user_id` was `null`??  That's not possible unless that's from the `mt_data` table directly.  A minimal test case would be helpful to see what you actually have.  Maybe you have an application issue, and not so much an SQL issue.